# Does anybody know a twitter bootstrap compatible combobox/autosuggest control?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am in need of a bootstrap compatible dropdown/autocomplete control that I can attach to a text field and opens prefilled with options when i put the cursor inside the textbox. At the bottom there should be an option to add a new item by t.ex. open a modal dialog on click. The user should also be able to enter his own text like with a combobox. This is functionality I have seen many websites use and it works very nicely.

More specifically my usecase is to fill out a invoice and to allow a user add a new product by clicking the "add new" link at the bottom. A modal popup will then open allowing the user to add details. When the modal closes and the product is saved for later the invoice line will then have Description, Price and Vat set. Also if the user selects one of the prefilled lines the product will be set for him. In case it is a one off product the user just enters the description and add price and vat manually.

The closest I have seen is [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) but it does not seem to do quite what I want. A kind of combo between the multiple and single functionality in select2 would be perfect. Also I am using angularjs as the client library

[image: Combo/dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

Angular-UI has a combobox based on Select2: [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I already saw that but its really just a wrapper around select2 so it does not add any additional features

Comment: So you want an additional link at the bottom to "add new client" and not the ability to add whatever the user typed into the typeahead if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Both. In my case specifically the dropdown options are products for invoice lines. By clicking "Add new" I can add a new product in a modal popup. In case the client just need a throwaway product he just adds the description manually. By selecting a item in the dropdown the description price and vat are set automatically

Comment: Doable, but you're in custom directive territory now. And as far as canned jquery stuff, I just recently did a canvas of them and don't recall seeing that particular feature. Almost all did the "add this item if it doesn't exist", but none with the additional link as you describe.

Comment: I added a better description to the original question. The perfect solution would be to expand select2 with this functionality and add a angular directive on top. I am not too good with javascript so I was hoping a solution already existed

Comment: If you're not too good with the javascript, I'd use what Angular-UI has and just include a separate link for the modal to add new. Not quite as elegant, but probably save you hours of fighting the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found Chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to be a very good for these situations. I have been using it with bootstrap on a new project with no major issues.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Of course the menu items could be populated dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Combobox Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{
    padding:20px;
}
.dropdown-menu>li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    padding-left:2px;
    right: auto;
    top:23px
}
.combobox-item{
    color:#aaa;
}
.combobox-item:hover{
    color:#000;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".combobox-item").unbind("click").click( function(e){
        var input = $(e.target).parents('li').children('input.combobox');
        if (e.target.className.indexOf("combobox-empty") == -1)
            $(input).val(e.target.innerHTML.trim()).attr("placeholder", "enter something").focus();
        else
            $(input).val("").attr("placeholder", "what other?").focus();
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <input type="text" class="combobox" placeholder="enter something" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="combobox-item combobox-empty">Other</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="combobox-item">Foo</li>
            <li class="combobox-item">Bar</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downvote as this doesn't have anything to do with AngularJS, which is tagged in the question (and how I found the question through a search).